# No context in callback from custom widget

Tags: design-patterns, flutter, callback

I'm new to Flutter so this is probably easily answered by someone with more experience than me. It's more of a question about design than a code problem.

Sometimes I want to write re-usable widgets and to make them somewhat generic I want to have callbacks for user input, so that the parent widget can subscribe and then take proper actions rather than hard coding routes etc. But I directly run into trouble if I for instance wants to navigate from my callback, as I then have no context. So how do I design this in Flutter?

Comment: Pass the context in callback

Comment: so are you extending `StatefulWidget`? if so, read `State<T extends StatefulWidget>` class properties

Comment: You can pass the `context`. It would be better if you show some code

Comment: Ah ok, I thought the context was local to every widget in the tree and that you should not use the context of a parent (but receive it only from the build function). Because I read something about the context having the constraints and size of that particular widget so I thought passing it around could be dangerous.

Comment: And yes, I'm extending StatefulWidget and I have a VoidCallback that it passed to it which will be called whenever a user presses an item in my widget. So I should save the context in the widget that gets called by the callback and use that reference perhaps? I will try making some example code later if you don't understand what I mean.

Comment: you dont have to save the context in the widget: see my first comment

Comment: Haha, ah I now, State has the context. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can always have an optional/required context parameter in your stateless widgets. For stateful widgets, context is usually available, but if you need the parent context for some reason, you can always pass it to your widget. Take a look at the example below

```
class GenericWidgetFoo extends StatelessWidget {
  final BuildContext context;
  final Key key;
  final String name;

  const GenericWidgetFoo(
      {this.key, @required this.context, @required this.name});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Center(
          child: Text(
        this.name,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As psink said above I just missed the fact that the extended State class actually has access to the context:

Properties

context → BuildContext
The location in the tree where this widget builds. [...]
read-only